# Qual é o equivalente a UserControl em ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

No Web Forms nós temos `UserControl`. Estes controles tem um *code-behind* e um layout. Eles podem ser usados em diferentes projetos/soluções sem depender de outras coisas.

Eu quero criar um controle que exibe vários elementos e alguns links/botões que "disparam um evento". Não quero que este controle fique ligado ao meu site, quero poder reusá-lo em outros websites.

Qual é o equivalente em MVC? É possivel compilar o `Controller` e a `View` em uma DLL e usar em outro projeto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que lhe atende é um [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx) ([*Creating custom HTML Helpers*](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)).

As duas maneiras mais comuns de criar componentes reutilizáveis no ASP.NET MVC são *partial views* e *html helpers*. Ao contrário das *views* e *partial views*, os *html helpers* são classes/métodos implementados como qualquer outro em seu projeto. O papel deles já é gerar o HTML final, ao contrário de uma view que precisa ser processada. Por isso distribuí-los em uma DLL é algo totalmente natural.

Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, *html helpers* podem sim fornecer componente mais complexos (ex: [WebGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.aspx)).

P.S.: *Teoricamente* seria possível distribuir uma *partial view* em uma DLL já que no processo elas são compiladas. Mas, se é que isso é possível mesmo, acredito que não é suportado pelo MVC, pois nunca vi nenhuma documentação ou prática a respeito.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o equivalente a WebUserControls para MVC seria o conceito de PartialView, conheça mais em : [Partial View in ASP.Net MVC 4 no Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-4)<sup>(en)</sup>

Comment: Bem-vindo Rodrigo. Como um site de Q&A, o importante são são as perguntas e respostas que estão contidas aqui. Informações relevantes postadas aqui serão úteis para indexação dos buscadores para que outras pessoas achem o conteúdo no futuro. Além disso quando a resposta tenha basicamente apenas um link, ele pode ficar desatualizado e no futuro não conter mais algo relevante para esta pergunta ou mesmo desaparecer. Além disso estamos discutindo esse tipo de resposta aqui: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links